# Did other Titans possess strength similar to that of Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I'm asking about the MCU version of Thanos, but I'll accept answers sourced from the comics if no MCU answer is available (which I think is likely).

Thanos comes from the planet Titan.  We see in *Infinity War* that Titan was destroyed, presumably in a resource-driven civil war previously predicted by Thanos.

We also see, in *Infinity War* and in *Endgame*, that Thanos can fight off even the most powerful Marvel heroes at need.

I'm wondering if the other inhabitants of Titan had strength and abilities similar to Thanos.  Because if there were a whole planet of beings like Thanos, it seems odd that they wouldn't have just seized whatever resources they wanted from others.

Comment: Thanos has a mutation which is why his skin is wierd and that is also why he is tough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Thanos a Mutant among Titans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187391/is-thanos-a-mutant-among-titans) - while there's not much MCU material on that question **yet**, it would belong there and is even covered by the tags used. You might want to consider adding a bounty for MCU-based answers there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanos was a rarity, if not unique amoung Titans.

From the [MCU wikia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Titans):

> Thanos was born on Titan, and due to his severe deformities, was
>   considered an anomaly by the Titan society and grew up as an outcast.
>   Despite so, Thanos loved his people nonetheless.

However there is also evidence that his people were also strong, but not as strong:

> [Thanos was born to A'Lars, a member of the Titans, *a race of
>   powerful, god-like beings* that evolved on the planet of Titan.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos)

(Emphasis mine)

Obviously there is much more comics evidence and that has already been answered in this post: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187394/84035

Comment: While this isn't a bad answer, if you know an earlier question would cover a new one, it's probably a better idea to flag the new one as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it, but the other answer only works for the comics so I decided not to.

Comment: As I was saying above in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211171/did-other-titans-possess-strength-similar-to-that-of-thanos/211174?noredirect=1#comment575304_211171), a MCU-based answer to the earlier one would be perfectly fine, as it wasn't restricted to comics (by the question); better to have all the info in one place, than bits scattered around.