# In the MCU, can the Eternals lift Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, mjolnir, eternals-2021

According to this [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOgzUR_64yM), Vision can lift Mjolnir irrespective of being worthy due to being a machine. Since the Eternals are also ultimately automatons in the MCU, would they be able to lift Mjolnir as well?

Comment: Your initial premise is incorrect. Being a machine does not have anything to do with Vision being able to weild the hammer.

Comment: Not overly familiar with the MCU, but I always thought it was a case of Mjolnir *deciding* to be lifted.

Comment: @Paulie_D, is there any in-universe evidence for the premise in question being wrong? I did link a scene supporting said premise.

Comment: I believe the restriction is against wielding Mjolnir, not against lifting Mjolnir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes this character worthy to lift Thor's hammer, Mjolnir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87008/what-makes-this-character-worthy-to-lift-thors-hammer-mjolnir)

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - In _Age of Ultron_, [most of the Avengers tried to lift Mjolnir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3bhQwY0KCY) and -- with the exception of Cap -- couldn't budge it at all. So it appears there is a restriction against lifting it, not just wielding it.

Comment: @galacticninja - I don't see how any of the answers to that question answer the question of whether the Eternals can lift Mjolnir or not. None of them even mention the Eternals.

Comment: Just because the questions premise is flawed does not mean it should be closed. A VTC  is not a super-downvote!

Comment: @LogicDictates: I reckon that counts as attempting to wield it. (But I could totally be wrong.)

Comment: @LogicDictates As the other question already covers OP’s premise - that Vision and the Eternals are automatons and could they lift Mjolnir - this question seems to be redundant. It also appears to be primarily opinion-based and likely to attract speculative answers, since the Eternals have not been seen with Mjolnir in the MCU so far.

Comment: @galacticninja - Debunking the notion that the Vision was able to lift Mjolnir purely because he's synthetic and not because he's worthy doesn't answer the question of whether the Eternals can or not -- especially as it's not entirely clear that _they're_ synthetic. For this question to be a duplicate of the one you linked to, one or more of the answers there would need to address the specific point of whether the Eternals can lift Mjolnir or not, and none of them do. Therefore, this question is definitely not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @galacticninja - There is a case for this being an opinion-based question, but I see two counters to that. Firstly, it doesn't explicitly ask for anyone's opinions. You can read that between the lines if you want, but you can also read it as a question that's seeking evidence-based answers. And even if one can't justify a definitive "yes" or "no" answer to this question using evidence, an answer saying "we can't be sure" is a valid alternative. Secondly, the question is based on two beliefs, both of which can countered with evidence rather than opinions, as shown in my answer.

Comment: I agree with LogicDictates, while the premise is flawed the base question is can any of the Eternals lift/wield Mjolnir. It not a great question and I am not sure it has answer beyond "we don't know" but it is on-topic and not opinion based.

Comment: A more basic version of this question would be: What if Thor left Mjolnir inside an elevator?  Or on the blade of a forklift?  Or any other purely mechanical lifting device without  any sort of consciousness?  We do know that the elevator at Stark Tower was able to lift *Thor* while he was holding Mjolnir, so it sort of did by extension, but would it have worked without Thor being there?

Comment: I always assumed if there was any sort of "cheat" in Vision being able to wield Mjolnir, it was due to the mind stone. It seems more likely that an infinity stone would be able to override Mjolnirs restriction more than the fact that he isn't a biological being.

Answer (score 30):

To me, the scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* where the Vision lifts Mjolnir implies that he did so because he was worthy, not because he was an android. At the time, he was trying to convince the Avengers that he was on their side (rather than Ultron's), but they weren't sure if they could trust him or not. Then, just as he picked up Mjolnir, he said...

> VISION: **So there may be no way to make you trust me,** but we need to go.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015)</sub>

... and the Avengers immediately stopped questioning whose side he was on, as though the very sight of him lifting Mjolnir was enough to make them trust him. That only makes sense if they thought he lifted Mjolnir because he was worthy, rather than him being able to bypass the worthiness enchantment due to being an android.

This interpretation is supported by what the director and writer, Joss Whedon, had to say about the scene in a podcast interview with Empire:

> "That came from a 'Do you know what would be cool?' moment. It’s the cheer moment of the film. And what’s great is that, like the Hawkeye thing, we’d set it up – **we’d unknowingly set it up, just by having that ['Who is worthy enough to Mjolnir?'] sequence, then with Quicksilver as well, trying to grab it and it throws him off. Both of those things were in the script before I came up with the idea of [the Vision lifting Mjolnir].**
>
> **I had done something similar in an episode of Angel, where I needed you to *know* someone was telling the truth.** It was, very simply, Angel saying, 'He hates it if you ask questions, he can’t lie.' So, you just accept that.
>
> So on the one hand, I want them all to trust each other and go into battle not as a coherent group, but when they finally all show up at the church, they really do come together for the first time. On the other hand, **I need them to take this guy with them, and I need something to say, 'All right, we’re off!' And that really does answer a lot of questions.** It was so much fun and so cute. Chris added the 'Nice work!' as he walked by Tony, by the way.
>
> <sub>[Joss Whedon Reveals 10 Avengers: Age Of Ultron Secrets](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/joss-whedon-avengers-ultron-secrets/)</sub>

With that in mind, I don't think the Vision lifting Mjolnir proves anything about whether any of the Eternals could or not. Nor is there presently any other evidence I'm aware of that proves anything in that regard, one way or the other.

---

Also, it's not entirely clear that the Eternals genuinely are synthetic beings. That's what they were led to believe by Arishem, but in the first post-credits scene in *Eternals*, Starfox is introduced as both an Eternal and Thanos' brother.

> PIP: Behold, the royal prince of Titan, **brother of Thanos,** the Knave of Hearts, defeater of Black Robert...
>
> STARFOX: Roger.
>
> PIP: Oh. Defeater of Black Roger. The great adventurer, Starfox of Mystery Planet.
>
> STARFOX: What a pleasure to make your acquaintance, **my fellow Eternals.**
>
> <sub>*Eternals* (2021)</sub>

Judging by the evidence presented in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/256183/122024), the MCU version of Thanos isn't a synthetic being, but one who was naturally born from biological parents. So, if Starfox really is his brother -- and note that Thanos is pictured with his parents and one sibling in concept art supplied within the linked answer -- he presumably isn't a synthetic being either.

As there's conflicting information on this point, we can't be sure of the truth either way, until more evidence comes in. That said, it wouldn't exactly come as any great surprise if it transpired that Arishem lied to the Eternals about their origins.

Comment: I feel like Starfox is the brother of Thanos in the same way that Gamora and Nebula are his daughters, and sisters to each other, or that Thor and Loki are brothers - that is to say, they're not even from the same *planet*, let alone blood relatives, they were just raised together.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It may not be canon in the MCU but according to Marvel they are brothers. Thanos' appearance is due to him being born with 'Deviant Syndrome.'  https://www.marvel.com/characters/starfox-eros

Comment: @LogicDictates, I had always presumed that the scene that I linked in the question was the more definitive answer as to why Vision could lift Mjolnir in the first place, even though Vision's act of lifting Mjolnir and handing it to Thor may have been sufficient to instil tentative trust towards Vision for the time being. While what I believed doesn't necessarily contradict what Whedon has had to say, it could just as well be that Tony, Thor, and Steve are just shooting the breeze in that scene while still believing (suspecting?) deep down that Vision is actually worthy. [1/3]

Comment: The fact that Stan Lee's character's truck in the first standalone Thor movie, and the Iron Man and War Machine gauntlets in the second Avengers movie, could not move Mjolnir, while the Helicarrier could take off with Mjolnir onboard in the first Avengers movie, suggests that Mjolnir, in the MCU, cannot be moved as long as the intent of lifting/moving/wielding Mjolnir by someone unworthy is involved somewhere in the causal chain thereof. This [sort of restriction is not present in the comics](https://rb.gy/4jhvn) or is at least not very consistent therein. [2/3]

Comment: These factors also make the MCU version of Vision simply being worthy the most parsimonious explanation. [3/3]

Answer (score 1):

In same part of the Marvel Universe in the comics, certain very VERY powerful beings could lift Mjolnir, but in the MCU it's been made very clear that it holds to the classic idea that its enchantment prevents it being lifted but nobody save whom is deemed "worthy".

The only possible way around that is that someone would have to be more powerful than Odin, who created the enchantment. So the question then would be "Are the Eternals more powerful than Odin?" and I'm prepared to bet the answer is no.

Now if you want to discuss the Celestials, possibly Galactus, or the higher beings in the MCU like the Living Tribunal or even Eternity themself, we might be able to go with a "maybe".

Comment: Which powerful beings in the comics have lifted Mjolnir without being worthy? Have any of these characters lifted the Earth-616 Mjolnir?